# Is dependency injection just another name for the strategy pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

Are these terms equal or are there any important differences between dependency injection and the strategy pattern? To me it seems like Martin Fowler just renamed the strategy pattern with a catchier name, am I missing something?